# top menu not showing after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, theme, frontend

I just upgrade from Mag CE 1.5 to 1.7.0.2 and heck, fall in to troubles in a row..fixed a few but stuck at top menu..

`app/design/frontend/default/tenniskarma/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` contains

```
* @see Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php echo var_dump($_menu) ?>
<?php if($_menu ==  ""): ?>

<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php echo 'test test test' ?>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

and istead of menu, it prints out `string ""` and `test test test`, meaning that I am not getting `$menu` back...

see [this](http://www.tenniskarma.com/zee/index.php/)

> MY menu does show at all, can somebody tell me whats happening with
>   me?

my page.xml holds

```
 <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="accountLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
</block>
```

for menu inclusion..

please help me..I am near to striking my head with wall

Comment: What is with the first `if` statement... should be `if($_menu)`

Comment: Did you try to copy the default template? if this works, then change it until you have your old styling - or an error occured, then you know what to fix

Comment: This looks like it's fixed now. Please add an answer explaining what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reindexing your site?  Todo so goto Magento's **Admin > System > Index Management**, select any Indexes that may need their Data Reindexed, and click Submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
```

to

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

level-top is not declared.